# Why my "while loop" does not stop

Tags: c#, while-loop

I have some lines of code like this.
can  anyone explain for me why "while loop" does not stop. it is keeping shows the result more than the balance.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const double balance = 303.91;
    const double phonePrice = 99.99;
    double a = 0;

    while (a < balance )
    {
        a = a + phonePrice; 
    }
    Console.WriteLine(a);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: It does exactly what you have written. The loop ends when a is bigger than balance and then you print a who is bigger than balance. What did you expect to happen here?

Comment: thats because you aren't increment. basically a is always zero without ever going up.

Comment: It should run 3 times.

Comment: @Laurel but `a` is not `const`

Comment: I thought it should be less than the "balance"?.

Comment: @KhoaBui It will be more because the loop will not terminate until `a` is greater than `balance`

Comment: @ARLCode It is incrementing. It is `a = a + phonePrice`.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle oh yep good call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are checking the value after add so it add first then check if `a` greater than `balance`or not so one time extra phoneprice is added with `a`. Make your while loop

```
while ((a + phonePrice) < balance)
  {
     a = a + phonePrice;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

It does exactly what you have written.
The loop ends when a is bigger than balance and then you print that a variable

If you expect to stop the loop BEFORE running out of money then you need to change the loop exit condition

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const double balance = 303.91;
    const double phonePrice = 99.99;
    double a = 0;

    // You don't want to run out of money, so check if buying 
    // another phone will bankrupt your finances....
    while ((a + phonePrice) < balance )
    {
        a = a + phonePrice; 
    }
    Console.WriteLine(a); // a = 299,97
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```